# A few doubtful nginx directives are confusing me

Tags: nginx, configure

I was following this DO article: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/nginx-location-directive

And have these doubts regarding nginx conf files directives:

- What if there are 2 non-regexp location blocks: having `/t` and `/s` and user types `/f`, then which location would be served, and under what logic?
- If a location directive has `^~   /somepath` prefix, and the visitor has typed `example.com/some` then would Nginx stop searching even at this partial match? If yes, then it should stop at `/` matching also? If so, then why that conf file should've any other location block at all? Because in any case, `/` would be matched at all times, then why bother having any other locations?!!
- When a user types `http://sub.example.com/somepath/?user=any` then what exactly is $host and what exactly is $hostname in it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What if there are 2 non-regexp location blocks: having /t and /s and user types /f, then which location would be served, and under what logic?

Neither of them, as they don't match the input.

When no location-specific blocks match, then the `root` configured at server level would be served, just like DocumentRoot in Apache httpd.

> If a location directive has ^~   /somepath prefix, and the visitor has typed example.com/some then would Nginx stop searching even at this partial match?

No, partial matches only work the opposite way. A regex can match only part of the input (unless explicitly anchored), but an input cannot match only part of the regex – the entire match is considered to have failed.

Non-regex comparisons follow the same logic. A location block for `/f` would accept the input `/foo` (as the entire `/f` match is satisfied), but not the other way around.

> If yes, then it should stop at / matching also? If so, then why that conf file should've any other location block at all? Because in any case, / would be matched at all times, then why bother having any other locations?!!

Because none of that is true from the beginning.

> When a user types `http://sub.example.com/somepath/?user=any` then what exactly is $host and what exactly is $hostname in it?

`$host` is based on the HTTP "Host:" header that the client requests, which in your example would specify `sub.example.com` as that's what was in the URL. (Though see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15414811) about how $host might differ from the original request.)

Comment: You said, "A regex can only match .... the entire match is considered to have failed." In this case of failed matching, what role `^~` sign has got here? Won't that symbol force-stop the further matching of the requested uri to the other regexp locations mentioned in the conf file? And last, can you pls point out what could be (called) $hostname in this client request: `sub.example.com` (I've understood about $host from your answer and from the answer, whose link is sent by you)

Comment: The `^~` symbol applies to an exact-prefix location block, and if the match _succeeds,_ it will prevent _all_ regex-based matching for that URL. (Not "other" regexp locations, as none of them have been processed yet at that point.) The symbol has no effect "in case of failed matching".

Comment: As for `$hostname`, the Nginx documentation says that this is the hostname of the local machine, and is not influenced by any client requests. But that *really* should have been a separate thread.